# Altium tracks being overlapped

Tags: pcb, pcb-design, altium, pcb-fabrication, pcb-layers

I'm using Altium Designer (20.0.13) to edit my old PCB. In some of my PCBs the tracks are overlapped during routing and pushing. I don't know why this is happening; even **Rules> Electrical> tracks overlapping** is also disabled. I have also imported preferences from the other PCB which is okay but here the problem is same.

[image]

Can anyone tell me why this is happening?

Comment: This PCB is not imported from other PCB design softwares

Comment: Shift+R toggles through push and shove modes.

Comment: @MattYoung I have tried it but no success.

Answer (score 3):

While routing, you can use <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> to change **Conflict Resolution** for interactive sliding/routing properties.

[image: Interactive routing properties window]

Make sure that this is set to something *other* than **Ignore Obstacles**.

If the nets are different and they overlap, it should get caught when you run DRC by the **Short-Circuit** design rule:

[image: Short-circuit design rule]

Answer (score 2):

In rules, try setting the electrical->clearance->clearance constraint to "different nets only", it may be set to diff pairs. As Matt said, Shift+R should change the modes.